# Refresh control not sliding screen back up after refreshing in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

I have added a refresh control to my table view controller and when I slide down the refreshing animation occurs and my refresh code runs. However after it finishes refreshing (Spinning animation gone) the table that i swiped down does not scroll back up and essentially there is empty white space.

This is the code I used to implement my refresh control.

```
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    } else {
      tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl
    }
```

And this is my refresh function

```
func refresh() {
    Feed.query(params) { feeds, error in
      self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
      if error == nil {
        self.oldIndex = nil
        self.feeds = feeds
        self.scrollViewDidScroll(self.tableView)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        self.checkIfEmpty()
      } else {
        Alert(view: self).show(error!)
      }
    }
  }
```

After I get data from my call then I endRefreshing.  Thanks! I am currently testing on iOS 10.2 simulator.

Comment: Try enclosing your endRefreshing code in main thread to see if it works: `DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }`

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. If you want to get credit add it as an answer and I will select it as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing your **endRefreshing** code in **main thread** to see if it works:

`DispatchQueue.main.async { self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() }`